# Can a directory be added to the class path at runtime?

Tags: java, classpath

In order to better understand how things works in Java, I'd like to know if I can dynamically add, at runtime, a directory to the class path.

For example, if I launch a *.jar* using *"java -jar mycp.jar"* and output the *java.class.path* property, I may get:

```
java.class.path: '.:/Library/Java/Extensions:/System/Library/Java/Extensions:/usr/lib/java'
```

Now can I modify this class path at runtime to add another directory? (for example before making the first call to a class using a *.jar* located in that directory I want to add).

Answer (score 51, accepted):

You can use the following method:

```
URLClassLoader.addURL(URL url)
```

But you'll need to do this with reflection since the method is `protected`:

```
public static void addPath(String s) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(s);
    URL u = f.toURL();
    URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Class urlClass = URLClassLoader.class;
    Method method = urlClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(urlClassLoader, new Object[]{u});
}
```

See the Java Trail on [Reflection](http://download.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/reflect/).  Especially the section *Drawbacks of Reflection*

Comment: this is not working form me.. i am not able to load class after this using Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");

Comment: There is a reason why `addURL` is not public OR private. This is a unnecessary brutal force method that shouldn't be used in production code. Java designers provided more than one way of doing what's needed.

Comment: seems like the cast to URLClassLoader is broken in Java 9 (https://community.oracle.com/thread/4011800 and others)

Answer (score 26):

Update 2014: this is the code from the accepted answer, by Jonathan Spooner from 2011, slightly rewritten to have Eclipse's validators no longer create warnings (deprecation, rawtypes)

```
//need to do add path to Classpath with reflection since the URLClassLoader.addURL(URL url) method is protected:
public static void addPath(String s) throws Exception {
    File f = new File(s);
    URI u = f.toURI();
    URLClassLoader urlClassLoader = (URLClassLoader) ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader();
    Class<URLClassLoader> urlClass = URLClassLoader.class;
    Method method = urlClass.getDeclaredMethod("addURL", new Class[]{URL.class});
    method.setAccessible(true);
    method.invoke(urlClassLoader, new Object[]{u.toURL()});
}
```

Comment: It would have been more stackoverflowish to edit the accepted answer, I think. No more duplicate answers, that's what we like at this site.

Comment: @Zeemee I hardly remember, maybe I thought this was an edge case. I simply decided to avoid the accepted answer too much; I did not want to go beyond author's intention.

Answer (score 12):

Yes, you can use `URLClassLoader`.. see example [here](http://download.oracle.com/javase/jndi/tutorial/beyond/misc/classloader.html). Doesn't use reflection.

-- edit --

Copying example from the link as suggested.

```java
import java.net.MalformedURLException;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLClassLoader;
import java.util.Hashtable;
import javax.naming.*;

public class ChangeLoader {
  public static void main(String[] args) throws MalformedURLException {
    if (args.length != 1) {
      System.err.println("usage: java ChangeLoader extra_classpath_url");
      System.exit(-1);
    }

    String url = args[0];
    // Save class loader so that we can restore later
    ClassLoader prevCl = Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader();

    // Use prevCl as parent, so we extend instead of replace
    ClassLoader urlCl = 
          URLClassLoader.newInstance(new URL[] {new URL(url)}, prevCl);

    try {
      Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(urlCl);
      Context ctx = new InitialContext();
      System.out.println(ctx.lookup("tutorial/report.txt"));
      ctx.close();
    } catch (NamingException e) {
      e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
      // Restore old loader
      Thread.currentThread().setContextClassLoader(prevCl);
    }
  } // main()
}
```

Comment: The example there are good and they avoid using reflection. But maybe you can copy them here - in case the link gets broken?

Comment: It is great that this avoids reflection but it comes at a price: You are not adding a path to your process classpath but creating a new class loader which includes the new path and use it within a concrete thread, in this case, your current thread. That means that any path added this way will be only noted on those thread with explicitly modified class loaders.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo which is, of course, the way it should be used - you're meant to nest your classloaders so they have a defined scope (what you do in application servers, osgi etc), not mutate your system classloader.

Comment: @eis Sure, but the OP was curious as to whether it was possible to add paths to the current process classpath.

Comment: @PabloFranciscoPérezHidalgo I don't think that's what OP intended. Anyway, I don't quite agree with the brut force method of reflection especially when it's not needed because Java folks provided ways to do it.