# Can a directory be removed from the class path at runtime?

Tags: java, runtime, classpath

It is possible to add a path to the classpath dynamically, see [Can a directory be added to the class path at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884393/can-a-directory-be-added-to-the-class-path-at-runtime).

My question is the opposite: is it possible to remove a directory from the class path dynamically?

Comment: Can you describe the use case?

Comment: Why on Earth would you need to do that?  What feature are you trying to provide to the user of the app.?