# How to load file from resources directory in Java

Tags: java

I am trying to load a properties file directly from the resources directory of my Java project and am getting a null pointer exception. Can someone pl explain how to do it?

Code-

```
String resourceName = "config-values.properties"; 
Properties props = new Properties();
try(InputStream resourceStream = getClass().getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName)) {
            props.load(resourceStream);
        }
```

My folder structure is - /src/packageName and /src/resources/

Comment: Did you use maven to generate the project skeleton, if so can you confirm that you dir structure should be src/main/java AND src/main/resources.
Otherwise, you may just need to use path as "resources/config-values.properties" in getResourceAsStream

Comment: Structure should be src/main/resources

Comment: The structure is not src/main/resources just src/resources @jatanp what do you mean by "need to use path as resources/config-values.properties"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Following code expects that the resource, you are trying to access, exists in your class path.

```
getClassLoader().getResourceAsStream(resourceName))
```

Assuming that your file exists in src/resources: You may add **src/resources/** in your classpath. I don't know which IDE are you using but here are some ways to add a directory in the classpath:

- **Intelli J** : [how to add directory to classpath in an application run profile in intellij idea?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/854264/how-to-add-directory-to-classpath-in-an-application-run-profile-in-intellij-idea)
- **Eclipse** : [How do I add a directory to the eclipse classpath?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25162773/how-do-i-add-a-directory-to-the-eclipse-classpath)
- **At run time** : [Can a directory be added to the class path at runtime?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7884393/can-a-directory-be-added-to-the-class-path-at-runtime)
- **At command line** : http://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2012/10/5-ways-to-add-multiple-jar-to-classpath-java.html

Answer (score 2):

Adding another way to do it without stream

```
File ourFile = new File(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("yourFile.txt").getFile());
```

and then you can do things like

```
ourFile.getAbsolutePath()
```

Answer (score 1):

```
InputStream resourceStream  = 
 getClass().getResourceAsStream("/package/folder/foo.properties");
```

Try above code.

Hope this will helps.